# Xcode 6 set default values for layout margins or disable them

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

This new feature of Xcode 6 is kinda annoying. Most of the time I don't need to set offset relative to margins, and if I do I may want to use values other than default 16. Is there a way to change default value or totally disable margins for my project (or for all projects in my Xcode)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot "turn them off" because they're built into UIView. You can set them to be zero:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
label.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0,0);
```

But you'd have to do it manually for every view. You could automate this for your own subviews by setting them after init and then overriding the setter with a version that throws any values passed in away. However... In general, its best to go with the flow and not fight the frameworks so I'd really suggest not trying to switch them off or ignore them.

Comment: Ah, so they're built in like layout guides? I just don't get the idea of these margins. What's the advantage? It's a common task to add views that are bound to their superview's edges, and now you have to turn off 'Constrain to margins' checkbox every time to do this. Or your UI can easily have default margins other than 16, and again you'll have to avoid relative to margin offsets.

Comment: Yes. It's also common (probably more common) not to have subviews right at the edge of their container view. A UITableViewCell is a good example of that.

Comment: True, but why should all views have same margins? And, if your margins are not exactly 16, setting offset to superview is easier and more intuitive than setting offset to predefined margin.

Comment: That is true but they've got to default to something so Apple made it the values from the HIG.

Comment: They could at least make it an appearance selector so it's easier to set a (custom) global default :(

Answer (score 2):

Simply hold Option key (⌥) in the constraints pop-up to toggle between constraining to edge VS margin of views. Simple!

See full answer here: http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/10/09/xcode-6-auto-layout-margin-annoyances